# Rails: One User Model but need different info on registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, registration

I have one user model and within that model I have roles (admin and general).  I am using Devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise and CanCan https://github.com/ryanb/cancan.

An **admin** creates the master account during their registration and then can register other users as well as edit their accounts.  This works.

Finally, I have changed it so that the users can log in using their username and not email because email is not necessary for the general user.

My current (main) registration form (used only by the admin) requires the following information: First Name; Last Name: Email; Username and Password.  I know that it is necessary for me to both validate certain fields and also make it so that usernames and email are unique. Both I know how to do.

**USER MODEL**

```
validates :username, :email, :password, presence: true
```

**DB MIGRATE**

```
add_index :users, :email,  :unique => true
```

My problem is that when the **admin** creates the other users email is not applicable and also I want to include additional fields.  Because email is not necessary and because I am using a single user model, validating that field or making it unique will not work. Or I do not think it will work?

If I do not want to separate out the model is their another direction I can approach this to solve the problem.  I am thinking two registration forms -- but still the issue of validation and uniqueness will be present.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a method in your application controller to create users like so:

```
def create_new_user
    u = User.create(:email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(99)}@example.com", :password => params([:password]), :username => params([:username]))
    u.save!
end
```

You could create a form that admin could use to get username and any other parameters you need to this method.

Alternatively, you can generate the devise views and customize them to suit your needs.

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Then you can move `:email` into a hidden field (it will still be present and so pass validation) in the form and set it randomly like above. This will handle the unique issue. You can also add other attributes like you wanted.

Keep in mind though that if you want to create a Devise resource while signed in as a devise resource, you'll have to customize a few things in the registrations controller.

Devise has some good info on custom views. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: settheline:  Thanks for the feedback -- I lean toward creating separate Devise Views -- but the issue of email is still one that bothers me --- unfortunately after thinking about it last night -- although I do not want to do this -- I do not see how I get around having two separate models -- I guess I was hoping for a Hale Mary -- if I go the route of "fake" emails everything gets messy -- and I think in the long run I will kick myself -- so unless anyone else has another alternative I will have to add this to my growing list --- one step forward two steps back ---

Comment: I'm not sure how having an extra column on your users table for `:email` will really be much messier or complex than splitting into two models, but you'd know more about your app than me.(; Good luck.

Comment: Having the extra column is not the issue and I already have it now -- I was not clear -- but if I go your route -- that column will have "real" emails for admins and "fake" emails for the other users -- do you not think that may cause problems or do you think I am over thinking it?  I have been known to do this sometimes

Comment: It depends what you're doing with your app I guess... What kind of problems do you foresee? If the only difference between admin and user is the email issue, I guess I don't see how that could cause any meaningful problems. But if you're adding a lot of other attributes to user that won't apply to admin like you mentioned in your post, it may be best to use two models.

Comment: settheline: Thanks for your feedback -- I think this is one that I will need to think about.  I am going to mark your answer as solving the problem since your solution will work -- just not sure if I will go that direction -- also I used your random generation in another part of the application -- thanks again ---